# Powershell - get diff of two files without consuming huge amount of memory - is there any alternative c# or c++ API?

Tags: performance, powershell, compare

I have two large files to compare (over 10 GB). The below command works fine for small files but seems to eat up RAM space on my machines.

How can I get diff of two files without consuming huge amount of memory ?

Any thoughts would be really appreciated.

```
robocopy.exe C:\Folder\ C:\Folder\ /l /nocopy /is /e /fp /ns /nc /njh /njs /tee  /log:c:\temp\FolderList.txt

$path = 'C:\Folder\'
$pattern = [regex]::Escape($path)
$newContent = @()
Get-Content -Path "c:\temp\FolderList.txt" | ForEach-Object {$newContent += $_ -replace $pattern, ''}
Set-Content -Path "c:\temp\FolderList.txt" -Value $newContent

(Get-Content C:\temp\FolderList.txt).Trim() -ne '' | Set-Content C:\temp\FolderList.txt

robocopy.exe C:\Folder2\ C:\Folder2\ /l /nocopy /is /e /fp /ns /nc /njh /njs /tee  /log:c:\temp\FolderList2.txt

$path = 'C:\Folder2\'
$pattern = [regex]::Escape($path)
$newContent = @()
Get-Content -Path "c:\temp\FolderList2.txt" | ForEach-Object {$newContent += $_ -replace $pattern, ''}
Set-Content -Path "c:\temp\FolderList2.txt" -Value $newContent

(Get-Content C:\temp\FolderList2.txt).Trim() -ne '' | Set-Content C:\temp\FolderList2.txt

Compare-Object -ReferenceObject (Get-Content c:\temp\FolderList.txt) -DifferenceObject (Get-Content c:\temp\FolderList2.txt)
```

---

LAST UPDATE

Folderlist.txt

```
C:\Folder\Data2\Documents\
        C:\Folder\Data2\Documents\1.txt
        C:\Folder\Data2\Documents\2.txt
        C:\Folder\Data2\Documents\3.txt
        C:\Folder\Data2\Documents\4.txt
        C:\Folder\Data2\Documents\5.txt
```

CompareLog1.txt

```
Data2\Documents\
C:\Folder\Data2\Documents\
        Data2\Documents\1.txt
        C:\Folder\Data2\Documents\1.txt
        Data2\Documents\2.txt
        C:\Folder\Data2\Documents\2.txt
        Data2\Documents\3.txt
        C:\Folder\Data2\Documents\3.txt
        Data2\Documents\4.txt
        C:\Folder\Data2\Documents\4.txt
        Data2\Documents\5.txt
        C:\Folder\Data2\Documents\5.txt
```

Desired output :

```
Data2\Documents\
Data2\Documents\1.txt
Data2\Documents\2.txt
Data2\Documents\3.txt
Data2\Documents\4.txt
Data2\Documents\5.txt
```

UPDATE -2  :

Output :

```
Data2\Documents\
C:\Folder\Data2\Documents\
Data2\Documents\1.txt
C:\Folder\Data2\Documents\1.txt
Data2\Documents\2.txt
C:\Folder\Data2\Documents\2.txt
Data2\Documents\3.txt
C:\Folder\Data2\Documents\3.txt
Data2\Documents\4.txt
C:\Folder\Data2\Documents\4.txt
Data2\Documents\5.txt
C:\Folder\Data2\Documents\5.txt
```

Comment: Why can't you rely on an external command line tool like default Windows tool `comp.exe` or  Microsoft  utility `WindDiff` or `winmerge` to get the diff/patch ?

Comment: Just to clarify, are you specifically trying to diff two robocopy log files? Or are you trying to compare two file system folders, and robocopy is just the route you’ve gone down trying to achieve that?

Comment: are you specifically trying to diff two robocopy log files?  yeap

Comment: Hmm, I wish there was a way to stream one line at a time from two files, like `get-content file1,file2 | % { compare-object $_[0] $_[1] }`, but it doesn't work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all, adding stuff to an array with `+=` is a known memory hog, because arrays have a fixed length and when you add new elements to it, the **complete** array needs to be reconstructed in memory.

So for the replacements and removing empty lines of each log file, I would recommend doing that like this:

```
robocopy.exe C:\Folder\ C:\Folder\ /l /nocopy /is /e /fp /ns /nc /njh /njs /tee  /log:c:\temp\FolderList.txt
robocopy.exe C:\Folder2\ C:\Folder2\ /l /nocopy /is /e /fp /ns /nc /njh /njs /tee  /log:c:\temp\FolderList2.txt

$path    = 'C:\Folder\'
$newFile = 'C:\temp\CompareLog_1.txt'  # have it create a new file instead of gathering all 10Gb in memory
$pattern = [regex]::Escape($path)
# use 'switch' to parse the log file line-by-line
# and write the processed lines to the new file.
# this will be lean on mmory, but takes a lot of disk write actions..
switch -Regex -File 'C:\temp\FolderList.txt' {
    $pattern { Add-Content $newFile -Value ($_ -replace $pattern).Trim() }
    default  { if ($_ -match '\S') { Add-Content $newFile -Value $_.Trim() }}  # non-empty or whitespace-only lines
}
```

and for the second logfile:

```
$path    = 'C:\Folder2\'
$newFile = 'C:\temp\CompareLog_2.txt'
$pattern = [regex]::Escape($path)
switch -Regex -File 'C:\temp\FolderList2.txt' {
    $pattern { Add-Content $newFile -Value ($_ -replace $pattern).Trim() }
    default  { if ($_ -match '\S') { Add-Content $newFile -Value $_.Trim() }}
}
```

Next you need to compare the new files `CompareLog_1.txt` to `CompareLog_2.txt`, but these probably are still very large I guess, so for that I agree with [Zilog80](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67456917/powershell-get-diff-of-two-files-without-consuming-huge-amount-of-memory-is#comment119231906_67456917) to best use a dedicated software.

Depending on what you like to see as result, you may also consider using the old `fc.exe` which works fast and is not memory hungry.
Something like

```
fc.exe  /C /N 'C:\temp\CompareLog_1.txt' 'C:\temp\CompareLog_2.txt'
```

---

You can speed up the writing of the files to compare by not using `Add-Content`, but a StreamWriter:
(this will create a file in Utf8NoBOM encoding)

```
$path    = 'C:\Folder\'
$newFile = 'C:\temp\CompareLog_1.txt'
$writer  = [System.IO.StreamWriter]::new($newFile)
$pattern = [regex]::Escape($path)
switch -Regex -File 'C:\temp\FolderList.txt' {
    $pattern { $writer.WriteLine(($_ -replace $pattern).Trim()) }
    default  { if ($_ -match '\S') { $writer.WriteLine($_.Trim()) }}
}
# clean up
$writer.Flush()
$writer.Dispose()

$path    = 'C:\Folder2\'
$newFile = 'C:\temp\CompareLog_2.txt'
$writer  = [System.IO.StreamWriter]::new($newFile)
$pattern = [regex]::Escape($path)
switch -Regex -File 'C:\temp\FolderList2.txt' {
    $pattern { $writer.WriteLine(($_ -replace $pattern).Trim()) }
    default  { if ($_ -match '\S') { $writer.WriteLine($_.Trim()) }}
}
# clean up
$writer.Flush()
$writer.Dispose()
```

Comment: ok ,  thanks but ,  trim function does not correctly for your script. I have updated my question. (5/11)

Comment: I have tried both StreamWriter: and your first script. but no luck.  btw , My  original script does correctly trim it.

Comment: @Arbelac Ah.. missed the Trim(). Added that in now

Comment: still same  :)  I have added my output called UPDATE -2

Comment: is there any comment ?

Comment: @Arbelac Should be fixed now